# Show new form selector on selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Have tried various times to get second input form to only show when the correct selection is made, will still show either way. New to js and unsure what I'm doing wrong.

As I'm new to html, it might have to do with my id's. Completely new to js but have worked with dart and it seems to be similar, but just can't put my finger on the problem.

```js
$("#job-type").change(function(){
 if ($(this).val() == "internals-civil") {
  $('#telecom-internal-civil').show();
  $('#internal-civil').attr('required');
  $('#internal-civil').attr('data-error');
 } else {
  $('#telecom-internal-civil').hide();
  $('#internal-civil').removeAttr('required');
  $('#internal-civil').removeAttr('data-error');
 }
});
$("#job-type").trigger("change");
```

```html
<div class="form-body">
            <div class="contact-labels">
              <label for="job-type">Job Type</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <select name="job-type" id="job-type" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected value selected
                  >Select one</option
                >
                <option value="internals-civil"
                  >Telecom Internals & Civil</option
                >
                <option value="fencing">Fencing</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-body form-body-telecom" id="telecom-internal-civil">
            <div class="contact-labels">
              <label for="internal-civil">Job Type</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <select name="#" id="internal-civil">
                <option value="" disabled selected value selected
                  >Select one</option
                >
                <option value="#">Blah</option>
                <option value="#">Flah</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's jquery not js, you didn't include

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Work example:

```js
$("#job-type").change(function(){
 if ($(this).val() == "internals-civil") {
  $('#telecom-internal-civil').show();
  $('#internal-civil').attr('required');
  $('#internal-civil').attr('data-error');
 } else {
  $('#telecom-internal-civil').hide();
  $('#internal-civil').removeAttr('required');
  $('#internal-civil').removeAttr('data-error');
 }
});
$("#job-type").trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-body">
            <div class="contact-labels">
              <label for="job-type">Job Type</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <select name="job-type" id="job-type" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected value selected
                  >Select one</option
                >
                <option value="internals-civil"
                  >Telecom Internals & Civil</option
                >
                <option value="fencing">Fencing</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-body form-body-telecom" id="telecom-internal-civil">
            <div class="contact-labels">
              <label for="internal-civil">Job Type</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <select name="#" id="internal-civil">
                <option value="" disabled selected value selected
                  >Select one</option
                >
                <option value="#">Blah</option>
                <option value="#">Flah</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```